# add created column to search critera?

Tags: sql

below is my search table proecedure that searches all columns. Ive added the CleanName column on the fly and need that be searchable in the other query, reason being if i currently search for "bob smith" im getting 0 matches but bob returns matches becuase of first name, so in this example cleanname is actaully full name

```
USE [ITAPP]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_SearchAllTables]    Script Date: 07/11/2013 10:57:43 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROC [dbo].[sp_SearchAllTables]
(
    @SearchStr nvarchar(255)
)
AS
BEGIN

declare @where varchar(8000)
declare @sql varchar(8000)
set @sql = 'select u.*,e.*, (u.Forename + '' '' + u.Surname) AS CleanName from tblUsers u join tblEquipment e on e.userid = u.id WHERE 1 = 1 AND ( 1= 0 '

select @where = coalesce(@where ,'' ) + ' OR  ' + case when object_name(object_id)  = 'tblUsers' then 'u' else 'e' end + '.[' +  name + '] LIKE ''%' + replace(@SearchStr, '''', '''''') + '%'' '
 from sys.columns where object_id in ( select object_id from sys.objects where name in ( 'tblUsers','tblEquipment' ))
 and collation_name is not null
set @where = coalesce(@where, '') + ')'

print @sql
print @where

exec(@sql + @where)

END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding this line

```
select @where = ' OR u.[Forename] + '' '' + u.[Surname] LIKE ''%' + replace(@SearchStr, '''', '''''') + '%'''
```

after the set statement fixed my issues

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only use columns from the source (or expressions containing those columns) in the `WHERE` clause

normally you'd add it to the `WHERE` clause this way:

```
WHERE (u.Forename + '' '' + u.Surname) LIKE '%' + @SearchStr + '%'
```

but doing that with the method you've chosen may not be possible.